# Proving that a matrix has linearly independent columns.

Tags: linear-algebra

Show that the columns of $\begin{pmatrix} 2a & 2b & 2c & 2d \\ d & -c & -b & a \end{pmatrix}$ are linearly independent if $a^2+b^2+c^2+d^2=1$ and $ad=bc$.

So for some $x_1,x_2,x_3,x_4\in\mathbb{R}$ I need to show that if $x_1\begin{pmatrix} 2a  \\ d\end{pmatrix}+x_2\begin{pmatrix} 2b  \\ -c\end{pmatrix}+x_3\begin{pmatrix} 2c  \\ -b\end{pmatrix}+x_4\begin{pmatrix} 2d  \\ a\end{pmatrix}= \begin{pmatrix} 0  \\ 0\end{pmatrix}$ then each $x_i=0$.

So $x_1a+x_2b+x_3c+x_4d=0$ and $x_1d-x_2c-x_3b+x_4a=0$, but after tons of algebra I'm not getting any closer. Am I missing some easy trick?

Comment: You can't have more than two linearly independent columns. Maybe the question is about rows? Double check please

Comment: I will, maybe that is why I'm having so much trouble

Comment: Sure you can https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Linear_independence